# Completable Future - Using Completable Future I am trying to the data from two different files

Tags: java, completable-future

I am trying to read the data from two different files one is in csv format and another file is from xml data.using completeFuture  I am trying to read the data from two files async. I am getting the type conversion error.
Please let me know whether I am following the proper approach to use the completefuture object here in the below code

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.util.function.Supplier (java.util.ArrayList and java.util.function.Supplier are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

code to read the data from main thread

```
    CompletableFuture<Object> csvdata = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync((Supplier<Object>) processdatacsv());

    CompletableFuture<Object> xmldata1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync((Supplier<Object>) processxmldata());
    List<String[]> csvfiledata = null;
    if (csvdata.isDone())
        csvfiledata = (List<String[]>) csvdata.get();

    List<String[]> xmlfiledata = null;
    if (xmldata1.isDone())
        xmlfiledata = (List<String[]>) xmldata1.get();

    private List<String[]> processdatacsv() {
        CSVReader reader = null;
        Resource resource1 = new ClassPathResource("sample.csv");
        try {
            String csvFile = resource1.getFile().toString();
            reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

            return reader.readAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while process csv records");
            return null;
        }
    }

    private List<String[]> processxmldata() {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("sample.xml");
        File file;
        try {
            file = resource.getFile();
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("record");
            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            List<String[]> dataList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) node;
                    String[] data = new String[3];
                    data[0] = eElement.getAttribute("reference").toString();
                    data[1] = eElement.getElementsByTagName("Number").item(0).getTextContent().toString();
                    data[2] = eElement.getElementsByTagName("des").item(0).getTextContent().toString();
                }
            }
            return dataList;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            LOGGER.error("Error while process csv records");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` you need a `Supplier`. This cannot be done by casting a list to the type `Supplier<Object>`. The correct way would be this:

```
CompletableFuture<List<String[]>> xmldata1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> processxmldata());
```

The reason for using a `Supplier` is that evaluation must not start immediately with the statement constructing the `Supplier`. The `Future` will start evaluation in the asynchronous thread.

Later on, if you really need the result, you must wait for it. The simplest way to do this is just:

```
xmlfiledata = xmldata1.get();
```

Have a look at the javadoc of the get method.

Answer (score 1):

Like the exception says: you can't just cast a list to a supplier object. A [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) is an object that has a [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html#get--)-method to request the object that it supplies (a list in your case).

In your code the files wouldn't be loaded asynchronusly, because you are calling the methods `processdatacsv` and `processxmldata` directly, so they would be executed directly. To execute the methods later (and in another thread) you need the Supplier (so the other thread can call the get-method and execute the code).

In the code you provided in your question it would be the easiest to use [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) like this:

```
CompletableFuture<List<String[]>> csvdata = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> processdatacsv());
CompletableFuture<List<String[]>> xmldata1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> processxmldata());
```

In this code snippet the part `() -> processdatacsv()` could be interpreted like: create a new Supplier object which calls the method `processdatacsv` from it's method `get`.

Or you can do it like this (maybe easier to understand):

```
CompletableFuture<List<String[]>> csvdata = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Supplier<List<String[]>>() {
    public List<String[]> get() {
        processdatacsv();
    }
});
CompletableFuture<List<String[]>> csvdata = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Supplier<List<String[]>>() {
    public List<String[]> get() {
        processxmldata();
    }
});
```